# How to exchange upgrades from first multi-tool to a second multi-tool?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Since the new "Synthesis" update (patch 2.23) you can have more then one [multi-tool](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Multi-tool). Is it possible to exchange some equipped upgrades from one multi-tool to another?

Example: I would like to swap the A-class scanner-upgrade from my first multi-tool to my second (with more slots).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there is no way to do this. Some of the upgrades may be able to be dismantled to get back some of the resources you put into them, but for the most part you'll have to start over again with the new one.